# call variable argument method by reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
public String testa(Object... args){
    for (Object arg : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
     }
    return "a";
}

@Test
public void test28() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Method method = ReflectionUtil.getMethodByName(NormalTest.class, "testa");
        //wrong number of arguments
//      method.invoke(this);
        //argument type mismatch
//      method.invoke(this, 123);
        //argument type mismatch
//      method.invoke(this, new Object[]{123});
        // argument type mismatch
//      method.invoke(this, new Object[]{new int[]{123}});
        //right
        method.invoke(this, new Object[]{new Integer[]{123}});
    }
```

`NormalTest` class has a `testa` method, use reflection to get this method and call it, in above 5 ways, only the last is successful, why need to pass variable arguments with nested array?

jdk version is 7.

Comment: I don't think it should be.  `Object` should accept anything at all, so something funky here.

Comment: Try to create an array of Integer instead and use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public String testa(Object... args)
```

is syntaxic sugar for

```
public String testa(Object[] args)
```

So it's a method expecting an Object array.

`Method.invoke()` expects an array of objects containing all the arguments to pass to the methods. So if the method took a String and an Integer, you would have to pass an Object[] containing a String and an Integer. Since your method takes an Object[] as argument, you must pass, to Method.invoke(), an Object[] containing an Object[]. That's what you're doing in the last attempt. But not what you're doing in every other attempt.